# Replacing right-angle brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, special-characters

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<b><a href="#">Home</a> > <a href="#">This Page</a></b>
```

How can I replace all instances of the plain text right-angle brackets `>` with these `⟩` in JavaScript/jQuery?

The result should look like:

```
<b><a href="#">Home</a> ⟩ <a href="#">This Page</a></b>
```

I tried:

```
$('b').text($(this).text().replace('>','⟩'));
```

But it almost made my browser crash...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `.text(function(){ $(this).text().replace(...) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will have to isolate text nodes

In example `<b>` tag:

```
var content=$('b').contents();
content.each(function(){
    if( this.nodeType===3){/* text node*/       
        this.textContent=this.textContent.replace(/>/g,'}')        
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6vSQx/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var t = $("b").html();
$("b").html(t.replace(/&gt;/g,"}"));
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zdwtm/3/)